# ES Lint Error When Passing Parameter to Method in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an ES Lint Parsing Error in my Vue page. This is occurring because my parameter I am passing to the method contains a "." symbol.

```
Error - Syntax Error: Unexpected token (1:1628)

<div class="text-sm font-medium" v-bind:class="{ highlight(coin.price_change_percentage_24h) }">
```

What is the solution to this syntax? Is there a way to escape this in the template file?

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/Callum9362/coins/blob/main/pages/coins.vue)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `highlight` as a computed property which returns a function that takes the price as parameter :

```js
    computed:{
      highlight(){
        return (priceChange)=>{
        if(priceChange < 0)
        {
          return 'text-red-900'
        }
        if(priceChange > 0)
        {
          return 'text-green-900'
        }
        return '';
       }
      }
    },
```

and bind it to the class without using `{}` :

```html
<div class="..." v-bind:class="highlight(coin.price_change_percentage_24h)">
```